# NPM failing to resolve dependencies

Tags: npm

I have a package(@polkadot/api) which depends on some other packages(@polkadot/keyring, @polkadot/util-crypto, and @polkadot/wasm-crpyto). I need to require each of these packages.

If I install the 3 transient dependencies, npm gives me an error like this:

```
Multiple instances of @polkadot/keyring detected, ensure that there is only one package in your dependency tree.
        5.6.3   /home/clay/projects/saito-lite/node_modules/@polkadot/keyring
        5.6.3   /home/clay/projects/saito-lite/node_modules/@polkadot/api/node_modules/@polkadot/keyring
Multiple instances of @polkadot/wasm-crypto detected, ensure that there is only one package in your dependency tree.
        3.2.3   /home/clay/projects/saito-lite/node_modules/@polkadot/wasm-crypto
        3.2.3   /home/clay/projects/saito-lite/node_modules/@polkadot/api/node_modules/@polkadot/wasm-crypto
Multiple instances of @polkadot/util-crypto detected, ensure that there is only one package in your dependency tree.
        5.6.3   /home/clay/projects/saito-lite/node_modules/@polkadot/util-crypto
        5.6.3   /home/clay/projects/saito-lite/node_modules/@polkadot/api/node_modules/@polkadot/util-crypto
```

If I removed @polkadot/keyring(for example), I get an error like this:

```
Cannot find module '@polkadot/keyring'
```

Can someone please tell me how I can tell npm to resolve these dependencies?? I think I could use an alias and just keep 2(actually 4) of each of these transient dependencies in my node_modules, but that hardly seems necessary when the versions are matching and I just need one version of each of them.

I feel like NPM is the one being dumb here, but is it me? Shouldn't this "just work"?

Answer (score 0):

Well, isn't it always the case that as soon as you write a question on SO you find the answer a minute later?

It turns out that "npm dedupe" seems to have solved my problem.

I'm going to leave the question here for now because I did quite a bit of searching and wasn't able to find any other question exactly like this. I also think there is room for a discussion about what is the proper way to handle this, whether the polkadot folks could handle this better.